# Insert into a table values as the result of a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have three tables Users, Roles and UserRoles. Users has a primary key called as Id, Roles has a primary key called Id and UserRoles has two foreign key references to Users and Roles called UserId and RoleId.

I need to insert into the UserRoles a UserId, RoleId pair as the result of a SQL query on the Users and Roles table.

The queries are something like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Email = 'something@something.com';
```

and

```
SELECT ID From Roles WHERE Name = 'Admin';
```

I need to use them like this:

```
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleId) VALUES (SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Email = 'something@something.com', SELECT ID From Roles WHERE Name = 'Admin');
```

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
INSERT INTO UserRoles (UserId, RoleId) 
     SELECT a.ID, b.ID 
     FROM Users as a,Roles as b 
     WHERE a.Email='something@something.com'
     AND b.Name='Admin';
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you..

```
  declare @userId int, @roleid int
    select @userId = Id FROM Users 
    select @roleid = Id from Roles
    insert into UserRoles (UserId, RoleId) value (@userId,@roleid)
```

Please consider your where condition into select queries.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to accept the answer given by @Manish since it doesn't require me to know the data type of the sql columns fields.

Comment: there can be multiple ways to achieve the same result and path.. :)